# How many kind of feature for region-based segmentation

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I have to use region-based to classify foreground (FG) and background (BG). I read many papers about that problem. However, almost papers that I read, they often using mean feature to compare the mean square error such as

```
(I(x)-mean(FG)).^2>(I(x)-mean(BG)).^2=>x belong to BG
```

Some authors add some condition that used statistical reigon (add sigma term). How about the other feature to discribe image region. Could you suggest to me some feature? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this function I created in Matlab called 'Quantisation', note this is for grey scale images. it automatically finds thresholds in the image and will classify all pixels under 1 of the categories, FG or BG:

```
function [quant2_A_min,quant2_A_max] = Quantization(fname)

% If there is less that one input argument 'B20.BMP' will be read in.
if nargin <1
    fname='B20.BMP'
end
% define fname as the variable 'X'.
X=fname;
%splits the image into 2 levels by obtaining 2 threshold values.
thresh = multithresh(X,1);
%Contructs a vector of max values so that the max value in each
%quantization interval is assigned to the 2 levels of o/p image
valuesMax = [thresh max(X(:))];
[quant2_A_max, index] = imquantize(X,thresh,valuesMax);
%Contructs a vector of min values so that the min value in each
%quantization interval is assigned to the 2 levels of the o/p image
valuesMin = [min(X(:)) thresh];
%use the output argument index to assign the MIN values to the output image
%instead if called imquantize again.
quant2_A_min = valuesMin(index);
%Display both 2 level images side by side
imshowpair(quant2_A_min,quant2_A_max,'montage');...
    title('Quantised Images (Min & Max)', 'FontSize',14,...
'fontweight','bold');
end
```

Comment: Sorry. I am asking about feature for region based segmentation